# Can I populate my tableview starting from the second element in an array? (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have an array of `[AnyObject]` and am populating my `UITableView` with it. I want the tableViewCells to begin populating from the second object in this array, effectively leaving out the first element.

So: cell index 1 = array element 2, cell index 2 = array element 3, cell index 3 = array element 4, etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: Consider to drop the first item (`dropFirst()`) before reloading the table view

Comment: Number of rows will be one less than total count of objects in your data source. Further more just add one to your indexpath.row to skip 1st element. You can see the details in below code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in this way

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.objectsArray.count-1;
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let obj = self.objectsArray[indexPath.row + 1];
        //set your customcell here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can. In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, fetch elements from your data model by adding one to your array index. The specifics vary depending on what you have in your data model, but this is trivially simple.